# MYSQL - Select count with group by with only a table

Tags: mysql

I have these data

```
idhouse  year
  7     2016
  2     2018
  2     2017
  3     2017
  4     2015
  14    2003
  3     2018
  5     2018
  4     2017
  4     2018
```

I want to counting the number of houses belong to two years.

I tried with mysql select but didn't work.
How I should do it?

EDITED

Sorry for my bad explanation.

I have only one mysql table.

Filtering by 2017 and 2018 and count the numbrer these houses, I should get these match:

```
idhouse  year
  7     2016
  2     2018*
  2     2017*
  3     2017*
  4     2015
  14    2003
  3     2018*
  5     2018
  4     2017*
  4     2018*
```

And the SELECT should be show 3

Comment: Show us your SELECT statement you tried and also provide the expected result set.

Comment: just an hint  ... COUNT

Comment: Exactly two, or just more than one?

Answer (score 0):

I assume a house can only appear once in a year. Try this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) nb_houses
FROM  (SELECT house
       FROM yourTable
       GROUP BY house
       HAVING COUNT(*)>1) A;
```

See this [**run on SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89ab4/7).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a PK on (house,year), if you just want to know how many houses are listed more than once, you can do this...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT x.house) total 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.house = x.house 
   AND y.year <> x.year;
```

Answer (score 0):

I asuming you're doing a web app with this question

```
SELECT house, COUNT(year) as count_year FROM table GROUP BY house HAVING COUNT(year) = 2
```

By using your data above, the result will be

house | count_year
____2 | _______2

Then if you are using server side scripting like PHP use `mysqli_num_rows` for get the number of row(s).

Or if you use other language, just adjust the algorithm to get the number of row(s)

Comment: I want to filter by two different years, you can see my edited

Answer (score 0):

With this Select I get it:

```
select count(*) from (select house from yourTable Where year = 2018 and house in (select house from yourTable where year = '2017')) A;
```

But can we improve this Select in terms of efficiency?

You can try [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/138eab/2)

Thanks.